libuuid in oracle linux 9.x
on running my java application (it's a a Sap Commerce 6.x, also knowed as Hybris) I have this error on oracle linux:
INFO  [localhost-startStop-9] [DefaultRMIRegistryService] Creating Registry on port 2198.
INFO  [localhost-startStop-9] [LocalRMISocketFactory] Creating server socket at '/127.0.0.1:2198'.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/xxx/git/yyy/riello-pim/bin/ext-integration/sap/core/sapcorejco/lib/linuxintel/libsapjco3.so: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1820)
...

searching on internet I understood that is releated to libuuid library that with the time is changed.
Now: on my linux, libuuid is installed, I checked.
What's the issue and how solve it?

ls /home/marcodaniele.coppola/git/riello/riello-pim/bin/ext-integration/sap/core/sapcorejco/lib/linuxintel/libsapjco3.so says what?

the file is present into the path... a green line: /home/marcodaniele.coppola/git/riello/riello-pim/bin/ext-integration/sap/core/sapcorejco/lib/linuxintel/libsapjco3.so

Yes it looks like the dependency libuuid is the problem. You might have to make sure all necessaries are in java.library.path, passing that variable as a JVM option

hi @g00se, thanks for reply. Can you give me an overview? I have libuuid present on my machine (if I run 'yum install libuuid', I have Package libuuid-2.37.4-18.0.1.el9.x86_64 is already installed.; probably the one istalled is more recent of the one of the path, that is into the project).

You might start with this: ldd /home/xxx/git/yyy/riello-pim/bin/ext-integration/sap/core/sapcorejco/lib/linuxintel/libsapjco3.so That will tell you what that library depends on.

ldd ~/git/yyy/yyy-pim/bin/ext-integration/sap/core/sapcorejco/lib/linuxintel/libsapjco3.so   linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7ed9000)  libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf780d000)  librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xf7808000)  libuuid.so.1 => not found  libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7611000)  libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf73e1000)  libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf7316000)  libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf72f6000)  libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf72f1000)  /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7edb000)

OK, so go back to this and ensure that all the directories there are in that variable. Start maybe with -Djava.ibrary.path=~/git/yyy/yyy-pim/bin/ext-integration/sap/core/sapcorejco/lib/linuxintel:/lib

the error is changed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/xxx/git/yyy/yyy-pim/bin/ext-integration/sap/core/sapcorejco/lib/linuxintel/libsapjco3.so: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Too many levels of symbolic links 

Just noticed libuuid.so.1 => not found from your previous. That needs to be fixed

The issue was the missing of 32bit version of the library.
for install 32bit:
# yum install libuuid.i686

for check the dependencies:
ldd ~/git/yyy/yyy-pim/bin/ext-integration/sap/core/sapcorejco/lib/linuxintel/libsapjco3.so 
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f64000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf7898000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xf7893000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/libuuid.so.1 (0xf7889000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7692000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7462000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf7397000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7377000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7372000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f66000)


Glad you got it fixed
